# Generic way to consume data from kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there is way to get list of all kafka topics and consume all data from it gererically using kafka.
We actually want to capture any kind of data flowing inside kafka .

Comment: One topic can hold JSON, another can hold XML... How are you expecting to make anything absolutely generic?

Comment: We are expecting topics to hold JSON only

Comment: Okay, so what's wrong with the string deserializer? Or writing your own / use Spring Kafka JSON deserializer?

Answer (score 0):

When subscribing a consumer you can specify a regex pattern instead of a topic list, see the [`subscribe()` method](http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscribe-java.util.regex.Pattern-org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener-).

By passing a regex to match all (like `.+`), it will subscribe and start consuming all topics.

Comment: One thing you might want to do is exclude topics starting with '_' or you'll get the offsets topic too (which you almost never want unless you are troubleshooting).

Comment: Thanks, getting topic liat is fine but each topic format would be diff right so how to deserialized it generic way thats big problen for me.